# how to validate two controls using one validator

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

i have two text boxes which the user should enter one of them 
i wanna to use a validator which act exactly like Required Validator ,
as when the user press Submit the red alert written by the controls 
any ideas

Thanks in advance

Comment: cuz it is correct if the user insert any one of the text boxes
i cant force him to fill both controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no built-in Validator that can do that, you will have to build a custom one:

try [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9522/CustomValidator-dependent-on-multiple-controls):

or you could try using the code behind and use onclick event to validate the textboxes and then return an error inside a span, like this:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TextBox1.Text == null) 
    {
        if (TextBox2.Text == null) 
        {
            errorMsg.InnerText = "Error" //use a span with runat server
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont get this line of code , could you please Explain more ?!

Comment: @omniaMm - try to use the code-behind example i provided instead.

Answer (score 0):

there was 2 ways to Solve this Problems and both of them worked correctly with me , and i let the client decide which one he prefer ,

1- use JavaScript at the ascx file

2- generate red labels when the user click submit to act like server side validation 
and that is what i used

aspx file

```
<asp:Label ID="PhoneLbl" runat="server" Visible="false" style="color:Red">(***) Enter Either Phone Number or Mobile Number</asp:Label>
```

behind code

```
protected void Sc_submit_button_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
PhoneLbl.Visible = false;

if (Page.IsValid == true)
    {

            if (txt_phonenumber.Text != string.Empty || txt_mobilenumber.Text != string.Empty)
              {
                    // any code }
              }
           else 
              {
                Sc_submit_button.Enabled = true;
                PhoneLbl.Visible = true;
                MobileLbl.Visible = true;
                txt_phonenumber.Focus();
                return;
              }
    }
}
```

and this work correct with me !!

Answer (score 0):

Use a CustomerValidation Control

When you drop a custom validation in your page, you can link the validator to a control, but if you want to perform multiple validations over more than one control, you need to include the following attribute

```
 OnServerValidate="MyMethodOnServerSide"
```

and define that method on the server side

```
protected void MyMethodOnServerSide(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mytxt1.Text) &&
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(mytxt2.Text))
            {
                args.IsValid = false;
                return;
            }

            args.IsValid = true;
}
```

just asign the `args.IsValid` property to the value you need. On the other hand the validation is done before you load the page, so if you clicked a button that performs an action like reading values from the DB in case everything is correct, on that action you need to include the following check.

```
protected void cmdSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
          LoadDataFromDB();
    }
}
```

When `args.IsValid` is false then `Page.IsValid` is false too. Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

You can do that with custom validators

Follow this tutorial [ASP.NET Custom Validator](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/validation/custom-validator/)